# SQL Server How do I change my view so it doesn't produces duplicates when inserting into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, triggers, duplicates

I Have  a View

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT [EmployeeNo.],
       SUM([HoursTaken]) AS HoursTaken
FROM [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm]
GROUP BY [EmployeeNo.]
```

And I want to put the output from this view into a table. 
Using

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees] 

SELECT * FROM v1;
```

Which Produces

```
EmployeeID  | HoursRequested |  
------------+----------------+
1           | 8              |     
2           | 16             |     
3           | 8              |
```

I have this View used with a trigger so when [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm] is updated or a new row inserted it produces duplicate rows on my table [dbo].[Employees]

How do I get it to just update the table [dbo].[Employees]
and not and not produce duplicates?

Comment: Your "view" does not generate duplicates - AT ALL - no matter what query is run against the view by itself. The problem lies with the code in your trigger which you have not shown. In addition, the idea that an insert into a table that is dependent on Employee (i.e., there should be a foreign key from your Form table to Employee) makes little sense.This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
 MERGE EMPLOYEES E 
using v1 
ON E.employeeid = v1.employeeno 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET E.hoursrequested = v1.hourstaken 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
  INSERT (employeeid, 
          hoursrequested) 
  VALUES (v1.employeeno, 
          v1.hourstaken);
```

For further info https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-merge-statement/

Comment: It gives me an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'."

Comment: can you try now

Comment: Different error "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'employeeid'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'employeeno'."

Comment: I think I the table name LWEmployees rather than Employees. I take it I just change it?

Comment: Try with the appropriate column name in the table and view, i have copied the column names from above.

Comment: Works a Charm, Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table. For example, you can synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one table based on differences found in the other table.

```
MERGE [dbo].[Employees]  AS target  
USING (SELECT [EmployeeNo.], HoursTaken FROM v1) 
    AS source ([EmployeeNo.], HoursTaken)  
ON (target.EmployeeID = source.[EmployeeNo.])  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE SET HoursRequested = source.HoursTaken  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (EmployeeID , HoursRequested)  
    VALUES (source.[EmployeeNo.], source.HoursTaken)
```

Any way, it not looks like a great idea to update the hole table on each view update.